# Get latitude and longitude based on city, zip or streetname

Tags: java, android, android-emulator, android-widget

In my current android application, I would like to get the geocordinates based on an entered city name, street name or zip code. How can I accomplish this?

Best Regards,
Rony

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check out the method [`Geocoder.getFromLocationName(cityName, maxResults)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html#getFromLocationName(java.lang.String%2C%20int)).

Use it like this:

```
List<Address> addressList = geoCoder.getFromLocationName(cityName, 1);
Address address = addressList.get(0);
if(address.hasLatitude() && address.hasLongitude()){
    double selectedLat = address.getLatitude();
    double selectedLng = address.getLongitude();
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Hi try the following code to get Geocode point from given address.

```
List<Address> foundGeocode = null;
/* find the addresses  by using getFromLocationName() method with the given address*/
foundGeocode = new Geocoder(this).getFromLocationName("address here", 1);
 foundGeocode.get(0).getLatitude(); //getting latitude
 foundGeocode.get(0).getLongitude();//getting longitude
```

Answer (score 1):

> Hi,
>
> There's a very nice site called the
>   World Gazetteer that has the data you
>   need, in a neat, downloadable file (by
>   city name)
>
> http://www.world-gazetteer.com/home.htm
>
> From the main page, click on the link
>   that says:
>
> other statistics.....various
>   statistics: tables, maps and
>   downloadable data
>
> and from the page that comes up, click
>   on the link that says:
>
> popdata (1.4 MB)
>
> Unzip the file, and you got it!
>
> The database is free master database
>   of world cities which includes
>   latitude, longitude, and population
>   data...etc.

Got this from: http://answers.google.com/answers/threadview?id=432778

Comment: Judging by the other answers, I am thinking that the `Geocoder` is probably the better solution rather than downloading a database of places and co-ordinates.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
Geocoder geoCoder = new Geocoder(getBaseContext(), Locale.getDefault());
try {
    List<Address> addresses = geoCoder.getFromLocation(latitude , longitude, 1);

    String strCompleteAddress= "";
    //if (addresses.size() > 0)
    //{
        for (int i=0; i<addresses.get(0).getMaxAddressLineIndex();i++)
            strCompleteAddress+= addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(i) + "\n";
    // }
    Log.i("MyLocTAG => ", strCompleteAddress);
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), strCompleteAddress, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
catch (IOException e) {
    Log.i("MyLocTAG => ", "this is the exception part");
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```